# How to implement a left join with some condition on second table in EF / EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

How to select data from table A (whole rows) join with table B when B has a Where clause?

What I need exactly is like this SQL code:

```
select * from HISBaseInsurs i left join (select * from HISBaseCenterCodeSends h where h.ServiceGroupID = 4 and h.CenterCode = 2) s on i.ID = s.InsurID
```

Result:

```
ID          Name                                               ID          CenterCode  ServiceGroupID InsurID     CodeSend        WebServiceAddress                                                                                    WebServicePassword                                 WebServiceUserName
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------- ----------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1           a                                                  2           2           4              1           asd6541         www.x.com                                                                                            23d                                                asda
2           b                                                  NULL        NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL            NULL                                                                                                 NULL                                               NULL
3           c                                                  NULL        NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL            NULL                                                                                                 NULL                                               NULL
4           d                                                  NULL        NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL            NULL                                                                                                 NULL                                               NULL
```

Now I want to have these like a list of entities. What I've done is:

```
list = HISBaseInsurs.Include(s => s.CenterCodeSends.Where(x => x.Center.CenterCode == 2 && x.ServiceGroup.ID == 4)).ToList();
```

But this solution has an exception. The exception message is:

> The Include property lambda expression 's => {from
>   HISBaseCenterCodeSend x in s.CenterCodeSends where
>   (([x].Center.CenterCode == 2) AndAlso ([x].ServiceGroup.ID == 4))
>   select [x]}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property
>   access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived
>   types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target
>   type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on
>   including related data, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Please share the domain classes.

Comment: first of all your sql query can be written like `select * from HISBaseInsurs i left join  HISBaseCenterCodeSends h on s on i.ID = h.InsurID where h.ServiceGroupID = 4 and h.CenterCode = 2` and second see these https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558389/2343086 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413698/2343086

Comment: @abdulqayyum As I said I want to select all rows of table A. but selection that you've written only select a row that accepts the condition.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) would help you?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var filteredCenterCodeSends = dbContext.HISBaseCenterCodeSends
    .Include( ccs => ccs.Insur ) // assuming navigation property name
    .Where( ccs => 
        ccs.Center.CenterCode == 2 
        && ccs.ServiceGroup.ID == 4 );
        // if ccs.Insur/ID is nullable, also add `&& ccs.Insur != null`

var insurersWithFilteredCcs = dbContext.HISBaseInsurs
    .GroupJoin( filteredCenterCodeSends,
        insr => insr,
        ccs => ccs.Insur,
        (insr, ccsCollection) =>
            new 
            {
                Insur = insr,
                FilteredCenterCodeSends = ccsCollection,
            } );
```